# android POST image files to php script using httpclient

Tags: java, php, android, post, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to post image files (PNG) to a php script so that I can get them from $_FILES, however, when I try to submit the data for upload my android app just sits there for a long time and I get a not responding message from the system. Are the files just taking too long to upload or am I doing something wrong?

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("PHP_SCRIPT_URL");

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String term = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.current_term), "000");
    String location = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.current_location), "000");

    EditText text1 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.entry_title);
    EditText text2 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.entry_comments);
    String title = text1.getText().toString();
    String comment = text2.getText().toString();

    MultipartEntity multi = new MultipartEntity();

    try {
        // Add your data
        multi.addPart("term", new StringBody(term));
        multi.addPart("space", new StringBody(location));
        multi.addPart("title", new StringBody(title));
        multi.addPart("comment", new StringBody(comment));
        File cacheDir = new File(this.getCacheDir(), "thumbnails");
        if (cacheDir.exists()) {
            File cacheFile;
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                cacheFile = new File(cacheDir, "photo_" + i);
                if (cacheFile.exists()) {
                    multi.addPart("media"+(i+1), new InputStreamBody(new FileInputStream(cacheFile), "photo_"+i));
                }
            }
        }
        httppost.setEntity(multi);

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        switch(responseCode) {
        case 200:
            check_success = true;
            break;
        default:
            check_success = false;
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("ERROR").setMessage("HTTP RESPONSE: "+responseCode).setNeutralButton("Close", null).show();
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("ERROR").setMessage("ClientProtocolException\n" + e.getMessage()).setNeutralButton("Close", null).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("ERROR").setMessage("IOException\n" + e.getMessage()).setNeutralButton("Close", null).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend doing something like this instead (using HttpPost), it is a little simpler: http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

Comment: Thanks! That helped get me on the right track. I now just need to figure out how to upload my image files... I updated the question/code